# Problem serving swf files in IE with Glassfish V3

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, glassfish, jersey

I have a problem with glassfish to serve swf files.
In my application there is a little swf file to use TableTools plugin on datatable and when I try to open this page with any browser everything goes fine, but with IE the behaviour is quite different the swf is not loaded and if I try to reach it with direct url an alert ask me to choice what the browser has to do with the file (Open, Save, Save as), I click on open but nothing is shown..
This problem appear only with IE.
it seems a content-type error because chrome show me this warning:
"Resource interpreted as document but transferred with MIME type application/x-shockwave-flash."

but I don't know how I can setup the correct content-type
my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>ManagementConsole</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/(img|js|css)/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>RedirectWrongRequest</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.italtel.patchfinder.filters.RedirectWrongRequest</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>exclude</param-name>
            <param-value>/LoginServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RedirectWrongRequest</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginError</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/loginError.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginError</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginError</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminPages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <!--<role-name>USERS</role-name>-->
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <!--None in http mode, Confidential in https mode-->
            <!--<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>-->
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/LoginServlet</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/LoginError</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
        <!--<realm-name>userauth</realm-name>-->
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <!--<role-name>USERS</role-name>-->
    </security-role>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Menu</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

from the image below you can see last 3 rows with the error loading swf file (with correct content-type)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh98S.png

Comment: Headers: Request URL:https://0.0.0.0/ManagementConsole/swf/a.swf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7
Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:1871
Content-Type:application/x-shockwave-flash
Date:Mon, 22 Nov 2010 15:09:11 GMT
ETag:W/"1871-1290437702000"
Last-Modified:Mon, 22 Nov 2010 14:55:02 GMT
Server:GlassFish v3
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!
problem was a bug in IE 6/7/8/9 and maybe older version, where when using a secure connection ssl, loading of swf file doesn't succeed because a bug in IE.
I've solved this problem by overriding the cache with a filter in my application:

```
        hresponse.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        hresponse.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", System.currentTimeMillis());
        hresponse.setHeader("Pragma", "");
        hresponse.setHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");
```

hope will be useful for someone else!
Thanks